# Retain ggplot2 citation when converting to plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I have to create a bunch of plots, and I've already made them using ggplot2. I would like to make them interactive by converting them into plotly. But, I run into a couple formatting problems. The most annoying of these problems is that I can't seem to retain the citations that I create at the bottom of the plots.

Here is some code to reproduce the error:

```
Names = c("eggs","milk","bread","I need to make some names longer")
Kilos = c("1","2","3","4")
df= as.data.frame(cbind(Names,Kilos))


plot_citation = "I need to include the citation for my data in the plot itself. 
Some of the citations are long, so they
take up
several lines."


TestGGPlot = ggplot(df,aes(y = Kilos, x = Names, fill = Names))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ABCABC","#ABCABC","#ABCABC","#ABCABC"))+
theme(legend.position = "none")+
coord_flip()+
xlab("Names")+
ylab("Kilos")+

theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+ 

 labs(caption = plot_citation,vjust=1,hjust=1)+
 theme(plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0))



TestGGPlot



TestPlotly = ggplotly(TestGGPlot)
TestPlotly
```

The ggplot looks like this:
[ggplot, looks good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B11Kk.png)

The plotly graph looks like this:
[Plotly graph. Note the missing citation and the y axis label shifted to the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80AxH.png)

I have included citations in plotly graphs by adjusting the domain the the plots, and adding an annotation underneath them, but I couldn't get that to work here. I don't know if plots created using the "ggplotly" function behave differently than normal plotly plots, or if I just don't fully understand the plotly syntax.

Thank you all!